# multi-dimensional dictionary to dataframe python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dictionary

```
dict_abc = {'A': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
         'B': [[4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 3],],
         'C': [[4, 6, 0]]
        }
```

I would like to convert this to a dataframe in the form

```
   | x | y | z |
A    1   2   3
A    4   5   6
A    7   8   9
B    4   4   4
B    2   2   3
C    4   6   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, read as Series, `explode` and convert again to DataFrame:

```
s = pd.Series(dict_abc).explode()
df = pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), index=s.index, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

output:

```
   x  y  y
A  1  2  3
A  4  5  6
A  7  8  9
B  4  4  4
B  2  2  3
C  4  6  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
In [2471]: x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_abc, orient='index').stack()
In [2478]: df = pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), index=x.index, columns=['x', 'y', 'z']).droplevel(1)

In [2479]: df
Out[2479]: 
   x  y  z
A  1  2  3
A  4  5  6
A  7  8  9
B  4  4  4
B  2  2  3
C  4  6  0
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem im having is these solutions dont work with old pandas, I am stuck with pandas 1.1.5 and can only use this version for now, due to work limitations

Comment: This should work with older pandas version as well.

Comment: droplevel gives an error

Comment: As per this [`documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), `droplevel` is available since pandas version `0.24.0` . What is the error you are facing?

Comment: Thanks, it worked after restarting my kernel

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dict_abc.values()),
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'z'],
                  index=chain.from_iterable([k]*len(v) for k,v in dict_abc.items()))
```

output:

```
   x  y  z
A  1  2  3
A  4  5  6
A  7  8  9
B  4  4  4
B  2  2  3
C  4  6  0
```